# Application Craft, PhoneGap and Parse - A match made in heaven?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, parse-platform, applicationcraft

If I wanted to design apps that required data storage and were targeted for multiple mobile platform's, would using Application Craft to create the UI, Parse to store the data and PhoneGap to wrap it all up for the relevant target device be a potential way of approaching this?

Sorry for the generic question, black and white answers are ok in return.

What would be the biggest limitation to this approach?

To keep it simple, lets say the app is to capture images and text input from multiple users, store it and then display it in some form of activity feed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with Application Craft, but it seems to be a paid version of PhoneGap -- meaning that they each seem to accomplish the same thing so use one or the other (unless I'm missing something...). PhoneGap can use jQueryMobile (or other frameworks) to help with the UI.

If you're going to use Parse within PhoneGap then you will need to find a PhoneGap plugin that allows Parse to work cross-platform. There likely are some, but if not you'll have to develop a separate plugin for each platform.